# Indexing a 2D numpy array with an array of column indices

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a 2D numpy array, A, of shape (N, D) and a 1D array, b, of shape (N,). I want to index the first array using the second to produce the following array:

```
arr[0] = A[0][b[0]]
arr[1] = A[1][b[1]]
arr[2] = A[2][b[2]]
...
arr[N-1] = A[N-1][b[N-1]]
```

This is easy to do with list comprehension, but I'm hoping for an efficient vectorized solution with numpy methods or indexing.

Comment: A complete example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy's [integer-array-indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

```
arr = A[range(N), b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i,x in enumerate(a): #loop iterate from a[0] to a[N-1]
  arr[i] = x[b[i]] #b[i] is from b[0] to b[N-1]
```